# Anylogic fluid batches, changing batch properties (size of batch, insert a batch) dynamically

Tags: dynamic, fluid, anylogic

I have a long pipeline (few hundred kilometers).  Batches of different types of fluid are injected into the pipeline, one after the other.  So now, somehow I want to access the batches in the pipeline and (1) change the size of a particular batch, (2) insert a new batch between two batches and update its size (3) link a parameter for the batch (such as an ID) and lookup the properties of this batch (access the batch, search for the corresponding ID, then lookup the properties).

The problem is this:  where the two fluid batches touches, they mix, creating a new batch, which is a mixture of the two fluids.  Thus at the injection end (entry-side) I might have injected two fluids (fluid 1 & 2), say 50,000 cubic meter each.  On the exit side, where the fluid arrives, there will be three products - fluid 1 of say 47,000 m3; then a new fluid - mixture, whose composition is 60% fluid 1, 40% fluid 2, of size 5,000 m3; then fluid 2 of size 48,000 m3.

So overall the mass balance is maintained, 100k went in, 100k went out, but there are three fluid-batches that come out, only two that went it, and by reading their "ID"s am able to determine the composition (for example "Fluid 3", which got inserted between "Fluid 1" and "Fluid 2" has composition 60% / 40%).

Thus somehow, at some point in time, I need to access the fluids in the pipe, insert a new batch, set the size and composition of this batch and update the size of the remaining batches.

Is there a way of doing this dynamically, or do you have to somewhere interrupt the process along the line, "capture" the content and re-inject?

Comment: in real life y0u can't just magically insert a new batch into a closed pipe, so why do you think it's a good idea to do it here? You need some sort of process to be able to do that.

Comment: In real life the "third" batch starts forming the moment you inject the second product onto the first.  If you inject Diesel and follow that with Petrol behind, the Diesel and Petrol will mix at the interface between the two products.  Depending on the velocity at which you inject (and density, viscosity, etc) the "intermix" will grow faster or slower - but at the arrival end you will have Diesel, an Intermix, then Petrol (although you only injected Diesel and Petrol at the other end).  If the power trips and the line stands long enough - you will only have one batch - a mixture

Comment: So you either inject Diesel, a small amount of "Mix" and Petrol, then dynamically shrink the batch size of both Diesel and Petrol while you increase the batch size of Mix as the batches move along the pipeline, or you wait until a significant enough amount of Mix has formed then inject it as a new batch?  Either approach requires you to access the batches in the pipeline and change their size dynamically.  Ideally the user should see a "Mix" that grows as it moves along in the Animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible with the fluid library to modify anything in the pipe while it's on on the pipe

I think the only way to do this, is to actually change the batch to whatever you want before it enters the pipe.

This will not look good if you use different colors for different batches since you want ideally to actually see the mix happening, but might be your only way to achieve this.

Another way i see this working, is by connecting pipes together and customize the initial batch during the connection. You will need to make some java magic for this.

Those are not ideal compared to what you want to do, but I think they are your only options.